# Typescript error Argument of type 'User | null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'User'

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase-authentication

This is my Angular component code

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/compat/auth';
import { reauthenticateWithCredential, User, UserCredential } from '@angular/fire/auth';
import { EmailAuthProvider } from '@angular/fire/auth';
import { getAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-update-password',
  templateUrl: './update-password.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./update-password.component.css']
})
export class UpdatePasswordComponent {
  constructor() { }

  updatePassword = new FormGroup({
    currentPassword: new FormControl(null, [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(6)]),
    newPassword: new FormControl(null, [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(6)]),
    confirmNewPassword: new FormControl(null, [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(6)]),
  });

  updateAccountPassword(): void {
    console.log('updatePassword:', this.updatePassword.value)

    const auth = getAuth()
    const user = auth.currentUser;
    const credential = EmailAuthProvider.credential(
      auth.currentUser?.email!,
      this.updatePassword.value.currentPassword!
    )

    reauthenticateWithCredential(user, credential).then(() => {
      // User re-authenticated.
    }).catch((error) => {
      // An error ocurred
      // ...
    });
  }

}
```

I'm getting the following typescript error(see the screenshot) from -

[image]

I can understand it's asking `user` parameter type should be of firebase `User` type, but it's getting type `null` for that.

New to typescript world. Need some help to fix this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`auth.currentUser` can be `null` if no user is logged in. You can use a [type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates:%7E:text=code%20called%20a-,type%20guard,-.%20TypeScript%20follows%20possible) that'll also ensure that this code runs only if a user is logged in as shown below:

```
updateAccountPassword(): void {
  const auth = getAuth()
  const user = auth.currentUser;
  // ...

  if (user) {
    reauthenticateWithCredential(user, credential).then(() => {
      // User re-authenticated.
    })
  } else {
    console.log("No user logged in")
  }
}
```